# MUI 5 Autocomplete choose attribute of object as value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My options looks like this

```
const options = [
  {
    "VaccinationType": "Sample"
  },
  {
    "VaccinationType": "Another Sample"
  }
]
```

Code:

```
const [vacType, setVacType] = useState('');

<Autocomplete
    value={vacType}
    onChange={(e, value) => {
        console.log(value);
        setVacType(value);
    }}
    options={options}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.VaccinationType}
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.VaccinationType === value.VaccinationType}
    renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
            />
    )}
/>
```

I tried logging my value it still outputs the object `{ VaccinationType: "Sample" }`. I want it to only output `"Sample"`

In MUI 4 I'm using this `getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option?.VaccinationType === value?.VaccinationType}`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you managed to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

So I think u forgot to use onInputChange and InputValue properties for MUI Autocomplete, according to https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/ these properties are needed in this case here u can read more https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/ so please check this solution which works for me:

```
const [vacType, setVacType] = useState<any>('Sample')
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('Sample')
const options: any[] = [
    {
        VaccinationType: 'Sample'
    },
    {
        VaccinationType: 'Another Sample'
    }
]

<Autocomplete
    value={vacType} //here u set default Value and change whenever it changes a list choice
    inputValue={inputValue} //here u set default Input and change whenever it changes by typing
    onChange={(event: any, newValue: any | null) => {
        setVacType(newValue)
    }}
    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setInputValue(newInputValue)
    }} // handles typing
    options={options}
    getOptionLabel={(option: { VaccinationType: string }) => {
        return option?.VaccinationType
    }}
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
        option?.VaccinationType === value?.VaccinationType
    }
    renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" size="small" />
    )}
/>
```

Hope it helps!
Also to answer your problem with console.log

your code:

```
onChange={(e, value) => {
    console.log(value);
    setVacType(value);
}}
```

exchanged to :

```
onChange={(event: any, newValue: any | null) => {
    console.log('newValue')
    console.log(newValue)
    setVacType(newValue)
}}
```

gives object but you on this Autocomplete provide objects then seting values is in objects so u just need to add console.log(newValue.VaccinationType) but not for setVacType(newValue) and Autocomplete will remember last choice

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete options care about the item of the array which you put. According to your code, each item has all object values.
I searched to find a way but I couldn't.

There is a way probably you already thought;

You can edit options parameter like **options={options.map(o => o.VaccinationType)}** and remove **VaccinationType** key on getOptionLabel and isOptionEqualToValue

```
<Autocomplete
    value={vacType}
    onChange={(e, value) => {
      console.log(value);
      setVacType(value);
  }}
    options={options.map(o => o.VaccinationType)}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
      option === value
    }
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" size="small" />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: I was avoiding mapping because my options will come from the api which array size I cant control. But I will reserve this answer when I cant find one

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you want to do that!,
You can simply use `value` object wherever you want, and use any key of the object, take the `value` object as it's then use `value.VaccinationType`.

But, if you want to do this:

```
<Autocomplete
    {...props}
    value={options.find(op => op.VaccinationType === vacType)}
    onChange={(e, value) => {
        console.log(value);                   //Result: { "VaccinationType": "Sample" }
        setVacType(value.VaccinationType);    // <==== Here, add `.VaccinationType`
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This will break because of this `value={vacType}`. I set it up as controlled component. The reason maybe because `Autocomplete` is expecting an object as the selected value. Although this was easily fixed in MUI 4 which is the `getOptionSelected` prop. It was renamed to `isOptionEqualToValue` in MUI 5 but now it does not work as intended

Comment: I updated the answer, changed value to `value={options.find(op => op.VaccinationType === vacType)}` .